# full width container with arrow at the bottom

Tags: html, css, spring-boot

I've been trying to figure out how to make full width section with the arrow pointing down at the bottom like the image bellow , there's a lot of solutions but none of them worked for me , i have heard about many approaches including svg, clip-path , pseudo elements and many more, i know css can be used to achieve it but i know nothing on how to make it. how do i make make it with any approach ?

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuGEm.png)

```
<section>
 <div >
<p>sample text</p>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: https://css-generators.com/tooltip-speech-bubble/

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this with pseudo-element and using border-left border-right border-top

```css
.bubble {
    width: 100%;
    background: #bf6300;
    padding: 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  
  .bubble:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid #bf6300;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    left: 25px;
    bottom: -19px;
  }
```

```html
<section class="bubble">
    <div >
        <p>sample text</p>
    </div>
</section>
```